# Latest Version of Ubuntu Desktop burned to DVD won't start through Windows 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, dvd, windows-10

I would like to begin programming so I just got a brand new 1TB hard drive to install Ubuntu onto and downloaded the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS disc image which I then burned onto a DVD-R disc. I read on the [installation guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) that all I had to do was put the Ubuntu DVD into the DVD drive and restart my computer, however when I did this the option to install Ubuntu did not come up. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, and help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to enter your BIOS boot menu and choose the DVD drive. The key you press depends on your computer model.

Answer (score 0):

Did you burn the iso file as an image?  If you wrote it to the CD as a file, then when you insert the CD while in Windows you will see the `ubuntu-stuff.iso` as a file on the CD.  If that is the case, it was not burned as an image.

If it was burned as an image, then it may be your computer is not trying to boot off the CD.  If you hold down the shift key while selecting restart in Windows 10, you will reach the Windows EFI menu.  This is an all blue screen with some options on it.

One of these options will be to **Use a Device** such as your CD or a usb installer.  If you are not using EFI, you can enter the BIOS and make sure your CD drive is first in the list of boot options (how to do this is BIOS dependent).

Comment: I checked my CD and the `ubuntu-stuff.iso` file is not there, so I know that I have burned as an image. However, when I go to the Windows EFI menu, the option to Use a Device is not there. Is there a way to fix that or should I just make my CD drive the first in the list of boot options? (my BIOS is Legacy btw so if you know how to do it with that it would be very helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I think the image iso is bad.  Thought it was me...  but after creating three toasters (I thought those days were long gone) I realize it is the iso file.  The md5sum was identical.

Comment: The image partially... boots, but doesn't quite get to the Ubuntu's splash screen.